# Python Parser that convert WebFocus codes into Python/SQL

Tags: python, sql, webfocus

I want to write a parser that converts WebFocus script into Python/SQL.  Any suggestion on where to start?  Should I try something like antlr?

It doesn't have to be 100% automated.